# Relative Time Model with missing time periods

Tags: difference-in-difference

I'm trying to replicate a relative time model to evaluate pre-treatment trends in a staggered diff-in-diff model. I've found the following description in literature (Rietveld, J., Schilling, M. A., & Bellavitis, C. (2019). Platform strategy: Managing ecosystem value through selective promotion of complements. Organization Science.):

> As noted previously, identification of the
>   treatment effect is only valid to the extent that there exist no
>   differences in the pretreatment trends between endorsed and
>   nonendorsed video games. One concern is that sales for a certain video
>   game on one platform are leveling off at a somewhat slower rate
>   compared than the same game on a competing platform. A platform
>   sponsor may see a greater potential for boosting a game’s unit sales
>   precisely because of this slower decay, which would then violate the
>   parallel trends assumption. To rule out this concern, we implement a
>   relative time model of which the main benefit is that it allows for
>   different lags and leads of the treatment effect (Autor 2003). An
>   additional advantage of this model is that it provides insight into
>   the dynamics of the treatment effect: whether the effect of
>   endorsement is constant or perhaps first picks up and then mean
>   reverts after an endorsed video game has been on the market for a
>   longer period of time. The relative time model replaces the vector of
>   treatments with a series of time dummies that indicate the relative
>   distance between week t and the launch of an endorsed video game. The
>   omitted category against which the coefficients are estimated is the
>   week preceding the endorsement, in which we also group all
>   observations for games that never received the endorsement (Seamans
>   and Zhu 2013, Greenwood and Wattal 2017). Results from this time-trend
>   analysis are depicted graphically in Figure B.2. The graph shows that
>   none of the pretreatment dummies are significantly different from
>   zero. This finding provides compelling evidence that there is
>   homogeneity in the pretreatment sales trends for games that eventually
>   receive the endorsement and those that never receive an endorsement,
>   validating the key identifying assumption of the DiD design (Angrist
>   and Pischke 2008). Furthermore, we note that the effect of endorsed on
>   unit sales manifests from the moment an endorsed game hits the
>   shelves; the effect then increases in magnitude in the following two
>   weeks a game is on the market, after which it levels off. The positive
>   effect ofendorsed on video games’ weekly unit sales loses statistical
>   significance after five weeks, equivalent to a cumulative sales
>   increase of 2,742 units.

I do understand what the authors do here. From my understanding they build a dataframe looking like this:

```
Firm Month Unit_Sales Treatment After Relative_Treatment
ABC  Jan    93  1   0   -4
ABC  Feb    4   1   0   -3
ABC  Mar    68  1   0   -2
ABC  Apr    62  1   0   NA
ABC  May    48  1   1   0
ABC  Jun    65  1   1   1
ABC  Jul    68  1   1   2
ABC  Aug    62  1   1   3
ABC  Sep    23  1   1   4
ABC  Oct    43  1   1   5
XYZ  Feb    51  1   0   -6
XYZ  Mar    4   1   0   -5
XYZ  Apr    20  1   0   -4
XYZ  May    61  1   0   -3
XYZ  Jun    31  1   0   -2
XYZ  Jul    25  1   0   NA
XYZ  Aug    39  1   1   0
XYZ  Sep    16  1   1   1
DEF  May    68  0   0   NA
DEF  Jun    44  0   0   NA
DEF  Jul    27  0   0   NA
DEF  Aug    5   0   0   NA
DEF  Sep    92  0   0   NA
DEF  Oct    42  0   0   NA
DEF  Nov    11  0   0   NA
DEF  Dec    83  0   0   NA
```

And then dummy code Relative_Treatment, Firm and Month, and calculate:

```
Unit_Sales = Relative_Treatment + Firm + Month
```

This is the "simple" case where there are no missing consecutive months for each firm. But what happens if a firm misses a month in between? In comparison (missing Observation from February):

```
Firm Month Unit_Sales Treatment After Relative_Treatment
    ABC  Jan    93  1   0   -4
    ABC  Mar    68  1   0   -2
    ABC  Apr    62  1   0   NA
    ABC  May    48  1   1   0
    ABC  Jun    65  1   1   1
    ABC  Jul    68  1   1   2
```

Or:

```
Firm Month Unit_Sales Treatment After Relative_Treatment
    ABC  Jan    93  1   0   -3
    ABC  Mar    68  1   0   -2
    ABC  Apr    62  1   0   NA
    ABC  May    48  1   1   0
    ABC  Jun    65  1   1   1
    ABC  Jul    68  1   1   2
```

Thanks in advance!